# KeepassX vs KeepassXC

Tags: keepass

While doing an `apt-cache search keepassx` I found two similar packages, `keepassx` and `keepassxc`. After installing and trying both, I have found that both appear identical, even the `man` page is the same for both packages (man page for keepassxc even refers to itself as keepassx). Is there a difference between the 2 packages?

Comment: What repository did you add to get them? Neither is in the standard Ubuntu archive.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [the KeePassXC website:](https://keepassxc.org)

> KeePassXC is a community fork of KeePassX, the cross-platform port of
>   KeePass for Windows. Every feature works cross-platform and was
>   thoroughly tested on multiple systems to provide users with the same
>   look and feel on every supported operating system. This includes the
>   beloved Auto-Type feature.

And [the FAQ:](https://keepassxc.org/docs/#faq-keepassx)

> KeePassX is an amazing password manager, but hasn't seen much active
>   development for quite a while. Many good pull requests were never
>   merged and the original project is missing some features which users
>   can expect from a modern password manager. Hence, we decided to fork
>   KeePassX to continue its development and provide you with everything
>   you love about KeePassX plus many [new features and bugfixes](https://keepassxc.org/project).

Since the `keepassxc` package only exists for 18.04, the problems with the manpage should be reported as bugs.

Comment: And how about keepass2 from standard Ubuntu repos?

Comment: @PawelDebski see https://superuser.com/a/879013/334516: keepassx was originally a port of keepass, and supports the keepass database format(s). See also keepassxc's FAQ: https://keepassxc.org/docs/#faq-keepass

Comment: @muru - at that FAQ link it says, "Database files in version 2 can be opened, but will be upgraded to a newer format."  It's not clear to me if it's saying that keepassxc is using a DB format that is some newer version beyond .kdbx.  Hesitating on switching from keepassx until I'm clear on this.

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness please find below my results.

I have found 2 available packages:

- keepass2, and
- keepassx

but both of them were not updated since 2016. I have found however info on [keepassxc](https://keepassxc.org/) [repo](https://launchpad.net/~phoerious/+archive/ubuntu/keepassxc) available with Ubuntu [packages](https://keepassxc.org/download/).

- keepassxc gets regularly updated and stays pretty current

This made the choice and the install straightforward:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc
[sudo] password for uadmin: 
 KeePassXC Password Manager (official upstream PPA)

Note to Xenial users who used keepassxc-beta before: you may need to uninstall/reinstall libsodium18 from the Ubuntu repositories if you are experiencing conflicts with libsodium32. See https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/1545#issuecomment-369163954
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~phoerious/+archive/ubuntu/keepassxc
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp28ijtjwz/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp28ijtjwz/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 0068FCD6 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp28ijtjwz/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 0068FCD6: public key "Launchpad PPA for Janek Bevendorff" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get install keepassxc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
...
```